# What is the difference between TryDequeue and TryTake in a ConcurrentQueue<>?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, producer-consumer, concurrent-queue

In the `ConcurrentQeueue<>` class, and extra method `TryDequeue()` is defined. But, as it implements `IProducerConsumerCollection<>`, it also has a `TryTake()` method. According to the docs, they both do the same thing:

[TryDequeue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-5.0):

> Tries to remove and return the object at the beginning of the concurrent queue.

[TryTake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.system-collections-concurrent-iproducerconsumercollection-t--trytake?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentQueue_1_System_Collections_Concurrent_IProducerConsumerCollection_T__TryTake__0__):

> For ConcurrentQueue, this operation will attempt to remove the object from the beginning of the ConcurrentQueue.

Why bother with implementing that `TryDequeue` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the difference between TryDequeue and TryTake in a ConcurrentQueue<>

According to available source code there is no difference as `TryTake` invokes `TryDequeue`

```
/// <summary>
/// Attempts to remove and return an object from the <see cref="Concurrent.IProducerConsumerCollection{T}"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="item">
/// When this method returns, if the operation was successful, <paramref name="item"/> contains the
/// object removed. If no object was available to be removed, the value is unspecified.
/// </param>
/// <returns>true if an element was removed and returned successfully; otherwise, false.</returns>
/// <remarks>For <see cref="ConcurrentQueue{T}"/>, this operation will attempt to remove the object
/// from the beginning of the <see cref="ConcurrentQueue{T}"/>.
/// </remarks>
bool IProducerConsumerCollection<T>.TryTake([MaybeNullWhen(false)] out T item) => TryDequeue(out item);
```

Souce: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ConcurrentQueue.cs,201

> Why bother with implementing that TryDequeue method?

`TryDequeue` follows expected name conventions associated with queues and is local to `ConcurrentQueue<>`. As well, `TryTake` follows naming convention normally associated with producer/consumer pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I reckon `TryAdd` calls `Enqueue` ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs that would accurate https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ConcurrentQueue.cs,184

Comment: `IProducerConsumerCollection<>.TryTake` is explicitly implemented in  `ConcurrentQueue<>`. Then it isn't possible to directly call `ConcurrentQueue<>.TryTake`. When you manipulate `ConcurrentQueue` you can use `TryDequeue` and when you manipulate `IProducerConsumerCollection` you can use `TryTake`

Comment: @vernou you are correct. You would first need to cast to the interface to access that member

Comment: This is all great, thanks. I am using the `IProducerConsumerCollection` in my class, so that I can inject it as a `ConcurrentQueue` for my unit tests.